# How can I write select statement in VBA with where condition

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to write sql select statement in VBA like this:

```
 Dim SQL As String
 Dim CITY_NAME As String
 Dim tbl As String
    CITY_NAME = Sheets("report").Range("D2").Value
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & tbl & "] where  CITY = " & CITY_NAME
```

so what what ever i write in D2 i got error
**Invalid column name**

but when i provide it manually like **CITY = 'london'** i got correct results 
I didn't understand the problem

Comment: You need to add single quotes around the CITY_NAME.

Comment: I tried and got syntax error

Comment: Try `where  CITY = '" & CITY_NAME & "'"`

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot @BrianMStafford